# Argon2 Web Application Java

Tags: java, web, hash, centos

I recently tested argon2-jvm 2.1 in Apache Tomcat 7.0.33 but when I try to use it I have this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found 
(required by /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/equifax/loader/linux-x86-64/libargon2.so)
```

Answer (score 1):

You most probably need a newer version of glibc package. Use `sudo apt-get install libc6`or whatever package manager your system is using (you didn't specify so I cannot be more precise) to install it. Note: if you're using a rather old distribution it may needs to be updated first as not all distributions support newer versions of glibc.